# z-index fixed IE7

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I have a problem with a fullsize background in IE7.
Here is the CSS code:

```
#passepartout {
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}
#supersize {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
#supersize img,
#supersize a {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:none;
}
#supersize .activeslide,
#supersize .activeslide img {
  display:inline;
}
```

I use a MooTools script too set the background fullsize: [MooSizer](http://mtness.net/demos/moosizer/). But in IE7 the background is in front of the other content.

Does someone know a solution?

Comment: It looks fine in IE7 too

Comment: I have a Content over the Fullsize-image.
Yes i works in IE7 but the Content #wrapper is in the back.
And the image is over the #wrapper

Comment: Post the HTML too? Or link to the page?